# Can a Dell battery of different series work on different series laptop?

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

I have Dell inspiron 3552 and i want to buy battery for it.On amazon , battery of different series are available .I called customer support and she told that battery of 4 cell and 40 Watts will work .I fear if battery of different series will fit on mine ? May be battery size not fit , how do i convince my self ?

Comment: You already got the confirmation that it would work, I also took a quick search on Amazon/eBay and they're batteries for your model.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Can you share that amazon link , i am from India may be it is not available here ?

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Dell-Original-Battery-Inspiron-Vostro/dp/B07G5Y6TFD/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_2?crid=52JA5Z9PV24F&keywords=dell+inspiron+3552+battery&qid=1564400534&s=gateway&sprefix=dell+inspiron+3552+ba%2Caps%2C160&sr=8-2-fkmr2

There it is. If you also go the customer questions there is a person who asked if it was compatible with your model and they replied yes. You can also contact the customer support if needed

Comment: @CaldeiraG Thanks !

Comment: The question isn't really clear on whose customer support gave you the advice.  4 cell 40 W doesn't tell you anything about battery compatibility.  If it was Dell customer support, I would trust the answer.  If it was some retailer, and they gave you that answer, I wouldn't, because if that's what they were basing their answer on, it indicates that the person may not have a clue.  Batteries have their own model number, and different computer models may use the same battery.  Go by the battery number.  (cont'd)

Comment: Resellers on Amazon often list the same battery by each computer model it works in just to get exposure.  So the fact that the right battery is listed for a different computer doesn't mean anything.